# The best way to record data on a page and implement pushstate()

Tags: javascript, html5-history

My website has a single page which the content is dynamically changed within one article element.

`<article id="dynamicArtile"></article>`

I am trying to use `pushState()` and a `popstate` event listener to create history entries so my website functions with the back and forward buttons on the browser.

I would like to store the content of the page in a `stateObj` variable like so:

`var stateObj = {content: dynamicArticle.innerHTML}`

I am not very sure on how to reload the previous page using the `stateObj` variable.

Any pointers or examples would be great. Staying away from JQuery if possible

Answer (score 0):

```js
function loadpage(url,f) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax'+url,
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(res){
    $('.dynamicArtile').html(res.content);
    if(typeof f === 'undefined')
      window.history.pushState({path:url},'',url);
  });
}

$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(e) { // only links that point to your site
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    loadpage(url);
    return false;
  });
  $(window).bind('popstate',function(){
    loadpage(location.pathname + location.search,1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### i think you don't use stateObj variable

sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know JQuery and would like to stick to just JavaScript

Comment: you use these functions, **addEventListener** and  **XMLHttpRequest**